# Django: How to dynamically change urlpatterns based on the hostname

Tags: django, django-urls

In Django it is possible to change the urlpatterns dynamically.

For example the i18n module is doing this.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/translation/#translating-url-patterns

I want something similar which is changing the pattern depending on the hostname for a view.

```
for exmaple for www.example.com I want:
path("articles/", views.articles),

www.example.it
path("articolo/", views.articles),

www.example.de
path("artikel/", views.articles),
```

There should be a lookup table for each hostname and a default value if it is not defined.

How could I do this without creating a new urls.py for each hostname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the method lazy to use methods as an url pattern:

Here is an example:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.utils.translation import get_language
from django.utils.functional import lazy
from django.urls import path

url_citylist = {
    'de': 'staedteliste',
    'pl': 'lista-miast',
    'en': 'citylist',
    ...
}

def get_pattern():
    current_language = get_language()
    if current_language in url_citylist:
        pattern = url_citylist[current_language]
    else:
        pattern = url_citylist['de']
    return pattern

def city_list_url():
    return r'^' + get_pattern() + '/$'


lazy_city_list_url = lazy(city_list_url, str)

urlpatterns = [
    url(lazy_city_list_url(), views.CityListView.as_view(), name='city_list'),
]
```

Comment: Are you sure the threadlocal language has been properly set when the URL is evaluated (Middleware has ran)? If not - get_language will always be default.

Comment: I have a middleware which sets the langauge for each call based on the hostname. If the hostname is unknown, i set a defaut language. But for me the interesting part was to use lazy. With lazy you can implement any case you need. If you are interested I could also add my middleware here.

Comment: You might enjoy this package - probably has some nice functionality you could look at. https://django-hosts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

Try with Django middleware

## myapp/middleware.py

```py
class DynamicURLMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        host = request.get_host()
        url_mappings = {
            'www.example.com': 'articles',
            'www.example.it': 'articolo',
            'www.example.de': 'artikel',
            # Add more hostnames and their corresponding patterns as needed
        }
        default_pattern = 'articles'  # Default pattern if the hostname doesn't match

        # Modify the URL pattern based on the hostname
        if host in url_mappings:
            request.urlconf = 'myapp.urls_' + url_mappings[host]

        else:
            request.urlconf = 'myapp.urls_' + default_pattern

        return self.get_response(request)
```

## myapp/urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/', views.articles, name='articles'),
    # Other patterns specific to www.example.com
]
```

## settings.py

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ... other middlewares
    'myapp.middleware.DynamicURLMiddleware',
    # ... other middlewares
]
```

## Project directory structure

```bash
project/
    |-- myapp/
    |    |-- urls_articles.py
    |    |-- urls_articolo.py
    |    |-- urls_artikel.py
    |    |-- ...
    |
    |-- myproject/
    |    |-- settings.py
    |    |-- ...
    |
    |-- manage.py
```

Comment: Do I need for each host a new urls.ypy?

Comment: yes ... i added the project directory structure in the answer

Comment: I want to do it without creating severall files. I would like to have a lookup table which i can easily extend. Currently I have this solution and loading for each hostname a new django instance with a different urls.py. But this gets very fast messy

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a dynamic URL patterns in Django based on the hostname without creating a new `urls.py` for each hostname, you need to use a combination of `middleware` and a custom URL pattern resolution.
This approach will allow you to have a single `urls.py` file while dynamically changing the URL pattern based on the hostname.

For that first, you need to create a custom middleware that will inspect the request's hostname and set an attribute on the request with the desired URL pattern:

```
class DynamicURLMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        host = request.get_host()
        url_mappings = {
            'www.example.com': 'articles/',
            'www.example.it': 'articolo/',
            'www.example.de': 'artikel/',
            # Add more mappings as needed
        }
        default_pattern = 'articles/'  # Set Default pattern

        # Custom attribute on the request with the desired pattern
        request.url_pattern = url_mappings.get(host, default_pattern)

        return self.get_response(request)
```

Next, add this middleware to your `settings.py` file.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ... other middlewares,
    'path.to.DynamicURLMiddleware', #Make sure path correct
]
```

Now, Modify your app `urls.py` file to use the custom attribute to dynamically change the URL pattern.

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views #Adjust If necessary

def get_dynamic_urlpattern(request):
    return [
        path(request.url_pattern, views.articles, name='articles'),
        # Add other URL patterns here & Adjust If necessary
    ]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', (get_dynamic_urlpattern, None, None)),
]
```

Here, the middleware sets a custom attribute on the request object based on the hostname. This attribute is then used in the `urls.py` to dynamically generate the URL pattern.

Answer (score 0):

#### All of the answers are very good

You can use whatever you want but if you are a very entry-level developer then I suggest you use functional programming otherwise do use object-oriented programming(OOP)

I followed `object-oriented programming(OOP)` as one of my active project for dynamic URL handling and that's why I like (Mahammadhusain kadiwala & Mohammad Golam Dostogir) answers.

Here is the Django [community forum discussion](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/how-to-route-domain-names-to-a-specific-view/2451/16)

If you want to implement it a different way then you could follow this [pakage](https://github.com/jazzband/django-hosts)